# Looking for Fira Sans by file name using the metropolis beamer theme (e.g. for Overleaf)

Tags: beamer, fontspec, beamer-metropolis

I'm using the `metropolis` beamer theme. In `beamerfontthememetropolis.sty`, the fonts are loaded by font name, *e.g.*:

```
\setsansfont[ItalicFont={Fira Sans Light Italic},%
                 BoldFont={Fira Sans},%
                 BoldItalicFont={Fira Sans Italic}]%
                {Fira Sans Light}
```

however, I need to look up the fonts by file name since I don't have them installed globally. The situation arises for example when using Overleaf. The Overleaf documentation just suggests to change the `\setXXXfont` commands so to tell `fontspec` to look up the font by file name instead of by font name, and this makes sense.

However, I'm not setting the fonts myself, but rather I'm loading the metropolis theme, which loads the fonts and sets lots of beamer options. I could of course take the font settings from the `metropolis` code, paste it in my own theme and change the code, but that looks dirty.

So is there a way to tell `metropolis` to load specific file names for the Fira Sans font, without copy/pasting code from the theme itself?

Another way could be to issue the `\setsansfont` command after the loading the theme. But in this case, is there a way to temporarily suppress the "font not found" errors?

Comment: Why do you need to load font by filename on overleaf? If metropolis is compiled with xelatex or lualatex, it uses fira font by default, even on overleaf

Comment: So do you mean Overleaf has Fira Fonts installed and the metropolis theme finds them out of the box?

Comment: Yes, as long as you compile with xelatex or lualatex.

Comment: That's good news. Is this something that changed (relatively) recently?

Comment: I don't know. After reading your question I tested it and it worked.

Comment: You could also download the FiraGO and Fira Math `OTF` files into a `./fonts/` directory and load from that with `Path = ./fonts/`. Then the filenames are whatever you downloaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is simple: just do nothing.

As long as the document is compiled with xelatex or lualatex it will use fira fonts per default which also works on overleaf.

The following image shows how to select the engine on overleaf:

[image]